# HP Elitebook 8570p / Windows 7 - Docking issues / After entering credentials, desktop is just a black screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, docking-station

When booting the laptop on a docking station, the logon screen appears and user X is able to input thier credentials.  Then the desktop does not load - just a black screen.  When the laptop is undocked, the desktop loads properly for user X and then you can dock the laptop and works just fine.  This is only happening for user X.  Other profile(s) load/work just fine when powering on the laptop while being docked and undocked.  Could this just be a corrupted profile for user X?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below is some info that I know off the top of my head.  If any more info is needed, I'll do my best to provide it.

HP EliteBook 8570p

Windows 7 Enterprise x64

Service Pack 1

2 external monitors

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that Windows is reading the dock as using another screen, so it is displaying your screen on a nonexistent screen and making your actual screen a blank screen.

Try booting into Safety Mode, then docking, and then if you can see your desktop, adjust the settings under Screen Resolution and disable second nonexistent monitor, or set to "mirror on both displays".

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But I am not sure if it is the display because a box appears for my companies encryption software on the primary monitor.  That is the only thing that appears other than the black screen (after logon).

Comment: Try it and then let me know and we can do some other troubleshooting.

Comment: That didn't seem to work.  I followed http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215.  Awaiting end user to log back in to test.

Comment: The microsoft link didn't resolve the issue either.  Probably just re-image the laptop as the last resort.